# Idiomatic way to implement `tail -f` in clojure

Tags: io, clojure

Disclaimer: This is just an educational task to learn how to program in Clojure and switch brain to immutable state-way of developing (the provided snipped has some unused variables which I didn't clean up since they will be used soon and are easy to understand).

The current milestone: to implement a solution that reads all lines from a file, if reaching file end - sleep and reopen a file, then continue trying reading the file *from the same place*.

This code is ugly without doubts. What makes me worrying is that it uses recursion in an ugly manner to maintain state. I think my next iteration will be to try using atoms to maintain mutable state instead of recursions, but not sure yet if it will be any better.

The `main` function currently for testing purposes just reads 3 lines from the channel.

```
(ns log-multiline-join.tailer
  (:use [clojure.core.async :only (>!! >! <!! thread chan timeout alt!)])
  (:import [java.io RandomAccessFile])
  (:gen-class))
 
(defn create-rac [filename]
  (RandomAccessFile. filename "r"))
 
(defn read-lines [rac position out stop]
  (.seek rac position)
  (if-let [line (.readLine rac)]
    (do
      (>!! out line)
      (recur rac (.getFilePointer rac) out stop))
    (.getFilePointer rac)))
 
(defn read-file-recur [filename position out]
  (let [rac (create-rac filename)
        position (read-lines rac position out 2)]
 
    (println "sleep")
    (Thread/sleep 1000)
    (recur filename position out)))
 
(defn tailer [filename out]
  (read-file-recur filename 0 out))
 
(defn -main []
  (let [out (chan)]
 
    (thread (tailer "/tmp/file" out))
 
    (println (<!! out))
    (println (<!! out))
    (println (<!! out))
 
    ))
```

Comment: You're braver than I am--if I had to do something like this in Clojure, I'd probably just call into Java.

Comment: @tsleyson hehe :-) PS: I added a link to the latest revision, which looks much better